# Restore hardware entries in UEFI from Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, uefi, bcd

After a missuse of efibootmgr under Centos 7, I have deleted every boot entries in UEFI, including USB, CD-ROM, DVD. So I couldn't boot anything.

I recovered Windows with the recoverer partition, but I unable to restore boot entries.

Of course I саn use only Windows, because I can't boot Live CD of Live USB.

I tried **bcdedit** but without success.
I'm looking bcdboot.exe but not sure it what I need.

How can I restore hardware boot options, or create them ?

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT : I already tried to turn off fast booting option and switch to legacy mode, but without any effect on boot option list.

---

EDIT2 : Well, I guess I will have to use Windows forever, bcdboot.exe didn't work for me.
In the BIOS menu I tried to reset settings to factory default, I enabled / disabled every options I found, nothing worked and I really don't know what to do next.
I also removed the BIOS's battery, just in case, it reset the conf, but of course not the boot entries.